# How to get Job_Requisition_Id in response of "create job requisition" request

Tags: workday-api

I am trying to "create job requisition" using SOAP webservice. The "Job requisition" create request is successful and I am get "WID" of the job requisition. However, I want to get the "Job Requisition ID" in response. Please advise.

I am sharing the response that I am getting currently.

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<env:Body>
<wd:Create_Job_Requisition_Response wd:version="v41.0" xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsvc">
<wd:Event_Reference>
<wd:ID wd:type="WID">bb1bc5d529d810014e54c54eec870000</wd:ID>
</wd:Event_Reference>
</wd:Create_Job_Requisition_Response>
</env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

I tried adding common header as below but no luck

```
        <bsvc:Workday_Common_Header>

            <!--Optional:-->

            <bsvc:Include_Reference_Descriptors_In_Response>true</bsvc:Include_Reference_Descriptors_In_Response>

        </bsvc:Workday_Common_Header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you've already found the answer at this point, but the ID would be in a node similar to `wd:Event_Reference` node, but named `wd:Job_Requisition_Reference`.

```xml
<bsvc:Create_Job_Requisition_Response bsvc:version="string">
    <!--Optional:-->
    <bsvc:Event_Reference bsvc:Descriptor="string">
        <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
        <bsvc:ID bsvc:type="string">string</bsvc:ID>
    </bsvc:Event_Reference>
    <!--Optional:-->
    <bsvc:Job_Requisition_Reference bsvc:Descriptor="string">
        <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
        <bsvc:ID bsvc:type="string">string</bsvc:ID>
    </bsvc:Job_Requisition_Reference>
</bsvc:Create_Job_Requisition_Response>
```

More than likely, the business process to create the job requisition is stuck in progress. You could check the business process by searching for the ID you do have in the tenant with the wid prefix `wid: bb1bc5d529d810014e54c54eec870000` to see the details of what happened.

If the process is stuck in progress, here are a few things to look into:

1. Check to see you aren't missing some subprocess or other data fields on your API request that the configuration in the tenant requires.
2. Check to see if you are using the `Run_Now` and `Auto_Complete` business process parameters in your request.
3. It is possible to add condition rules to the business process to skip certain steps if the business process is kicked off from an integration/API request.